# jQuery Combine Ajax Objects From Instagram API

Tags: jquery, ajax, instagram, instagram-api

I have 2 problems.  My ultimate goal is to make a request to Instagram and filter the images by tag.  Instagram doesn't allow for more than 33 images at a time so right now I have an ajax inside of another.  The first request gets images and then checks if there are more, if there are more I make another request.  So here are my 2 problems.

**#1** - I can't combine these 2 objects into 1. I have tried everything I could think of or find online.

```
var new_data = $.extend({}, data, data2);
```

and

```
$.extend(data, data2);
```

are not working, it just gives me 1 of the objects back

**#2** - My logic below is somewhat flawed, because this would only allow me to get 66 images max (2 request, 33 images each).  What I really need is to have the ajax in a loop of some sort. But I'm not sure how to do that.

```
var userid = '#######';
var token = '############';
var url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/' + userid + '/media/recent/?access_token=' + token + '&count=33';

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    cache: false,
    url: url,

    success: function(response){
        var paging = response.pagination;
        var data = response.data;
        console.log(data);

        if(paging.hasOwnProperty('next_url')){

            url = paging.next_url;

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                cache: false,
                url: url,
                success: function(response2){
                    var data2 = response2.data;
                    var new_data = $.extend({}, data, data2);
                }
            });

        }else{
            // No more images so create image gallery
        }
    },
    error: function(){
        // error stuff
    }
});
```

Here is sample of what I am getting back from Instagram

[image]

Comment: Edited. It should work now

Comment: Did you solve your problem? If so could please mark my answer, as I put a lot of effort into it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested. It works. Try

```
var imageData = [];
$(function() {
    var url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/smpspree/media/recent/?client_id=81e3d3f35c8a4438964001decaa5a31f&count=11'; 

    getData(url, function() {
        for (var i in imageData) {
            console.log(imageData[i])
        }
    }); 

    function getData(url, callback){ 
        $.ajax({ 
            type: 'GET', 
            dataType: 'jsonp', 
            cache: false, 
            url: url, 
            success: function(response){ 
                console.log(response.data)
                imageData = imageData.concat(response.data)
                var paging = response.pagination; 
                if (paging.hasOwnProperty('next_url')) { 
                    getData(paging.next_url, callback) 
                } else {
                    callback.call();
                } 
            } 
        }); 
    }

})
```

Comment: Yes Instagram only lets u get 33, but it defaults to 20, so the 33 is there to set it to max. In your code example I am getting errors, one is your missing the ( after your if, not sure what the others are

Comment: Fixed if error and next_url error. what sort of error do you get?

Comment: It was related to images.push(response.data), I believe it said images was not a function

Comment: actually it was undefined is not a function

Comment: I think this is working, give me some more time to test it out and see if its returning whats expected.  Much cleaner than what I was attempting.

Comment: Awesome!  Very nice logic, way better than what I was trying.  However, I am confused by the results I am getting back in the inspector.  Take a look at http://imgur.com/w2ghlpR , notice the very first array is an array of 3 arrays (the 3 requests, which is perfect).  Everything after that seems the same, maybe I am not understanding it correctly.  Also, in the picture how would I access "full_name" and check the value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76261/discussion-between-riddlemethis-and-said-kholov).

Comment: This was close but in the end the code had to many errors and wasn't returning the results correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to concat the elements of two arrays, then you're using `$.extend` wrongly.

**#1** In order to accumulate an array's contents, you use the `Array.prototype.concat` function. 
Example:

```
var new_data = data.concat(data2);
```

Note: `$.extend` is used to merge content. See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/.

**#2** Instagram includes a pagination key in all its responses. You can use this in your callback to trigger another ajax request.  See **pagination** in https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/

Note: Rate limits apply: 5,000 / hour per token for Authenticated calls. See https://instagram.com/developer/limits/

Comment: OMG thank you for number #1 - I didn't realize that the objects were in an arrays, I tried every method for joining objects I could find when all I needed was to join the 2 arrays!  What do you mean "in my callback function"?  Are you saying I wouldnt need multiple ajax calls like I have?

Comment: can u give me an example of how to use the callback function, I cant figure it out